# SQL wildcard issue

Tags: sql

I have a database which can be modified by our users through an interface. For one field (companyID) they should have the ability to place an asterisk in the string as a wildcard character.

For example, they can put in G378* to stand for any companyID starting with G378.

Now on my client program I'm providing a "full" companyID as a parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE companyID = '" + myCompanyID + "'
```

But I have to check for the wildcard, is there anything I can add to my query to check for this. I'm not sure how to explain it but it's kinda backwards from what I'm used to. Can I modify the value I provide (the full companyID) to match the wildcard value from in the query itself??

I hope this maked sense.

Thanks!

EDIT: The user is not using `SELECT`. The user is only using `INSERT` or `UPDATE` and THEY are the ones placing the * in the field. My program is using `SELECT` and I only have the full companyID (no asterisk).

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) target! You should be glad that you found it now.

Back to your problem, when users enter `'*'`, replace it with `'%'`, and use `LIKE` instead of `=` in your query.

For example, when end-users enter `"US*123"`, run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE companyID LIKE @companyIdTemplate
```

set `@companyIdTemplate` parameter to `"US%123"`, and run the query.

I used .NET's `@` in the example, but query parameters are denoted in ways specific to your hosting language. For example, they become `?` in Java. Check any DB programming tutorial on use of parameterized queries to find out how it's done in your system.

**EDIT :** If you would like to perform an insert based on a wildcard *that specifies records in another table*, you can do an insert-from-select, like this:

```
INSERT INTO CompanyNotes (CompanyId, Note)
   SELECT c.companyId, @NoteText
   FROM Company c
   WHERE c.companyId LIKE 'G378%'
```

This will insert a record with the value of the `@NoteText` parameter into `CompanyNotes` table for each company with the ID matching `"G378%"`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's a little more backwards than that. The users are not selecting anything from the table, they are INSERTING or UPDATING, it's my program that is doing the SELECT and my program only has the FULL companyID (no wildcards).

Comment: @PaulG I don't understand this: users cannot insert with a wildcard, and an update with a wildcard would work just the same as an update with the exact id (except possibly touching more records if the wildcard-based condition is matched by multiple rows). Just replace their asterisk with your `%`, and use `like` instead of the precise company ID.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, it's a backwards problem. They fill in fields from an interface and then they supply the companyID for which that data applies to. If they want that data to apply for all companies who ID starts with ABC for example then that's where the wildcard comes in. I'm just not sure how to work this on my side in my SELECT statement.

Comment: @PaulG I think I see what you mean. Take a look at my last edit.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help but that's not what I'm trying to do. I think I'll have to SELECT companyID FROM table and then loop through each one with some regex and see if my FULL companyID matches anything and modify it as necessary, then run another SELECT with the modified ID. Sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat implementation dependant and you did not mention which type of SQL you are dealing with.  However, looking at MS SQL Server wildcards include % (for any number of characters) or _ (for a single character).  Wildcards are only evaluated as wildcards when used with "like" and not an = comparison.  But you can pass in a paramater that includes a wildcard and have it evaluated as a wildcard as long as you are using "like"

Comment: Don't forget `_` for the single character wildcard

Comment: Thanks, I focused on % since he had asked about *.

Answer (score 0):

in TSQL I would use replace and like. ie:

```
select * from table where companyid like replace(mycompanyid,'*','%');
```